# Appending a specific string in GREL

Tags: openrefine

I'm cleaning data in Open Refine, using GREL. I'm trying to append the string OOL to the string SCH, only if SCH is placed at the bottom of any cell. I'll appreciate anny tips.

Miquel Centelles

Answer (score 1):

Assuming when you say "if SCH is placed at the bottom of any cell" you mean that SCH are the last three characters in the string then you can use the GREL function 'endsWith' within an 'if' function:

if(value.endsWith("SCH"),value+"OOL",value)

This adds "OOL" if the string ends with SCH, otherwise it just leaves the string as it was originally

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Owen. Ceratinly, I meant that SCH are the last three characters in the string. I supose there is any way to enchain two or more conditions; for example: if(value.endsWith("SCH"),value+"OOL",value) and if(value.endsWith("HIGH"),value+" SCHOOL",value). Any tip to do it? Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem. You can have multiple conditions by using another 'if' statement as the 'false' outcome for the first 'if' statement: `if(value.endsWith("SCH"),value+"OOL",if(value.endsWith("HIGH"),value+" SCHOOL",value))`. This can get unwieldy if you have several conditions. In OpenRefine there isn't a huge cost to doing this in two steps, so as an alternative you can just do each 'if' statement separately in two Transform operations which may prove more manageable and allows rollback of the steps separately which can be helpful

Comment: Thank you very much, Owe. I've tested second solution, and it's more efficient.